# Finding Duplicate Accountss

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables and I'd like to list all of the accounts which share an `IP`. For example, if account with the `Id` 1 and an account with the `Id` 2 had a `Session` with the same `IP`.

The account table:

```
Name: Account

Id   ... (more column names here)
```

The session table:

```
Id   Creator   Token   Expires   IP
```

I've tried the following so far but it doesn't quite work.

```
SELECT `Account`.`Id`, `Account`.`Username`, `Session`.`IP` 
FROM `Session` 
  JOIN `Account` 
    ON `Account`.`Id` = `Session`.`Creator` 
WHERE `IP` != '' 
GROUP BY `Session`.`Creator`;
```

Comment: Does something like "`Account`.`Username`" work? Why do you have backticks all over?  I dont think any quoting is needed in this except for the 2 comparisons, in which you can should probably use single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(`Account`.`Id`), 
GROUP_CONCAT(`Account`.`Username`),
 `Session`.`IP` 
FROM `Session` 
JOIN `Account` ON `Account`.`Id` = `Session`.`Creator`
 WHERE `IP` != ''
 GROUP BY `Session`.`Creator`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will give you the comma seperated list of account ids,Usernames who have same `Creator`

Note: Be ware of that fact it has a default limit of 1024 characters to concat but it can be increased which is defined in manual

Answer (score 0):

You find the IPs with multiple accounts

```
SELECT
   IP,
   COUNT (DISTINCT Creator) 
FROM
   `Sessions`
GROUP BY IP
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Creator) > 1
```

Now you've got to join the result of this query with your account table:

```
SELECT
    a.Id,
    a.Username,
    s.IP
FROM
    Account a
INNER JOIN
    Session s
ON
    a.Id = s.Creator
WHERE s.IP IN (
    SELECT
       IP,
       COUNT (DISTINCT Creator) 
    FROM
       `Sessions`
    GROUP BY IP
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Creator) > 1
)
```